# "The system is running in low-graphics mode" after installing proprietary Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 15.04 work on my computer since few hours and I'm stuck with one problem.

I got a problem ([this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/996989)) and a solution for this was to install the Nvidia proprietary driver.

I try to install it from the "Software and Drivers" graphical interface (v346 proprietary and tested) but at the first reboot, my computer give me the message "The system is running in low-graphics mode".

I tried many things (but I'm not specialist): install bumblebee, the linux-header, tweaking with the X.org config file... but nothing work.

If anyone can help, I would appreciate that!

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - you most likely have a setting in the BIOS that says Intel-graphics-acceleration = Enabled.

Apparently on some motherboards this is set by default, and you have to set it to Disabled to not conflict, and get past the low-graphics mode error. Set Intel-graphics-acceleration to disabled if you use the Nvidia for output, and it should work properly :)